# Set shipping method programmatically Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I just created a custom Woocommerce shipping method with the id of `custom_shipping`.  The option now appears on the Woocommerce -> Settings -> Shipping admin page.

I would like to set the shipping method dynamically based on a user's credentials.  The default method is `flat_rate` right now.

**Question:**
How can I set the shipping method to `custom_shipping` for users who meet a requirement, for the entirety of their session?

**Tried:**

```
$chosen_methods = $woocommerce->session->set('chosen_shipping_methods', array('purolator_shipping');
```

This sets the session variable 'chosen_shipping_methods' correctly on my `cart` page, but upon moving to `checkout`, the session goes back to using the `flat_rate` shipping method.

There must be a hook or filter that I can plug into to change the shipping method upon cart-session creation or something. (When a user adds something to cart for first time).

I would ideally like to set the new shipping method before anything else is loaded so the shipping method looks correct on their cart and checkout summaries.

Guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `woocommerce_before_checkout_shipping_form` hook

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_shipping_form', 'before_shipping');

function before_shipping( $checkout ) {

    // check the user credentials here and if the condition is met set the shipping method

    WC()->session->set('chosen_shipping_methods', array( 'purolator_shipping' ) );

}
```

Just a note to say that, on the cart page if the user changes the shipping method from default to some other method, the code above will again revert it to the default method on the checkout page, which will be a bit confusing for the user.

Answer (score 3):

```
// WC()->session->set('chosen_shipping_methods', array( 'your_shipping_rate_id_here' ) );
```

example:

```
WC()->session->set('chosen_shipping_methods', array( 'flat_rate:1' ) );
```

Comment: Work for me WC()->session->set('chosen_shipping_methods', array($id_shipping) );

Comment: I don't why but for some reason, this isn't working for me , the default shipping method is the wp_local_pickup and I work on a cart API.